# mysql several count and join returns strange value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, count, left-join

I'm trying to make a count within several table with `JOIN`, but when I made several `JOIN`s the `COUNT`s got wrongly counted.

Basically I've got 4 tables, named:

1. predective_search
2. predective_to_product
3. predective_to_category
4. predective_to_manufacturer

I want to count the total number of products, categories and manufacturer which has same id in table predective_search.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT * , 
    COUNT(pp.predictive_id) AS total_products, 
    COUNT(pc.predictive_id) AS total_categories, 
    COUNT(pm.predictive_id) AS total_manufacturers 
FROM predictive_search ps 
LEFT JOIN predictive_to_product pp ON (ps.predictive_id = pp.predictive_id) 
LEFT JOIN predictive_to_category pu ON (ps.predictive_id = pc.predictive_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_predictive_to_manufacturer pm ON (ps.predictive_id = pm.predictive_id)    
GROUP BY ps.predictive_id
```

Also the `GROUP BY` is needed I think. I'm stuck at this as I'm not getting any way to do this

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    ps.*,
    agg_pp.total_products,
    agg_pc.total_categories,
    agg_pm.total_manufacturers
FROM predictive_search ps 
LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT pp.predictive_id, COUNT(*) AS total_products
        FROM predictive_to_product pp 
        GROUP BY pp.predictive_id 
    ) agg_pp ON ps.predictive_id = agg_pp.predictive_id
LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT pc.predictive_id, COUNT(*) AS total_categories
        FROM predictive_to_category pc 
        GROUP BY pc.predictive_id 
    ) agg_pc ON ps.predictive_id = agg_pc.predictive_id
LEFT JOIN ( 
        SELECT pm.predictive_id, COUNT(*) AS total_manufacturers
        FROM predictive_to_category pm 
        GROUP BY pm.predictive_id 
    ) agg_pm ON ps.predictive_id = agg_pm.predictive_id
```

Comment: I found the solution of this problem just couple of min. ago:        SELECT *,(SELECT count(*) FROM oc_predictive_to_product pp WHERE pp.predictive_id = ps.predictive_id) AS productCount, (SELECT count(*) FROM oc_predictive_to_category pc WHERE pc.predictive_id = ps.predictive_id) AS categoryCount, (SELECT count(*) FROM oc_predictive_to_manufacturer pm WHERE pm.predictive_id = ps.predictive_id) AS manufacturerCount, (SELECT pu.url FROM oc_predictive_to_url pu WHERE pu.predictive_id=ps.predictive_id) AS url
FROM oc_predictive_search ps

Comment: Can you check this out; is there any problem with this code but it works well. Is this slow the execution time??

Comment: Its takes----------------> Showing rows 0 - 3 ( 4 total, Query took 0.0008 sec)

Comment: Your code should work.  As a matter of aesthetics I don't like subselects that refer to table aliases declared in the enclosing scope, but this is permissible on most modern RDBMSes, and many people write SQL this way.  Your code may or may not be faster - I can't run a query against your DB so can't say for certain.